# how would i clear previously echoed result without affecting any other functions in php?

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, ajax

I am currently working on website where it has a search box to search for specific items. The page echos out results in table format. So far everything works perfectly but when I try to filter the result(depending on features), I get two sets of results. One with previously displayed result table and the other is the filtered result. I do not want previous result to display back again on screen without affecting any other procedure. Something like sessions?? I do not know exactly how to deal with this situation.

```
<?php

include'search.php';// form for a search box. 


         if (isset($_POST['search_name']))  {
$search_name=mysql_real_escape_string(htmlentities(trim($_POST['search_name'])));
$errors = array();

if (empty($search_name)){

    $errors[] ='please enter a search term';
    }
else if (strlen($search_name)<3){
    $errors[] = 'your search term must be three or more characters'; 
    }
else if (1==2){
    $errors[] ='your search for '.$search_name.' returened no results';
    }
if (empty($errors)){



   filter($search_name); //it display another form in the navigation bar to filter the search result.


   search_results($search_name);//searches for all the result onthe database depending on the keyword  entered in searchbox. 


    } else{

    foreach($errors as $error)  {
        echo $error,'</br>';
        }
    }

}

?>
```

Comment: Code would be useful here

Comment: Yes, let's see your code!

Comment: Please provide some code.
And use the SEARCH function to see if there are another questions like this.

Comment: my code is quite nested in different files so i've edited the code where all the things begin from. hope it helps.

Comment: I can already tell you the problem is most likely in your AJAX/Javascript code.

Comment: i haven't used any AJAX/Javascript code. but do i need to? i mean the problem is when the two function: filter($search_name ) and search_results($search_name) runs. i get the result list through search_results and another form in navigation bar through filter and when i submit the filter form it runs another function and it displays the filter result, and filter form in navigation bar and also the search_result function's result. the problem is i don't want search_results function to run when filtering the search. it's kinda confusing, i'm sorry.i'm not very good with explaining.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this code:

```
echo 'world';
echo 'hello !';
```

You can intercept the echo using [`ob_start()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php), [`ob_get_contents()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-get-contents.php) and [`ob_clean()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-clean.php).

```
ob_start();
echo 'world';

var $echoed = ob_get_contents();
ob_clean();

// real echo
echo 'hello ' . $echoed . '!';

// now you see
// hello world!
```

Because the ob 'output buffering' is native to PHP, you can use it with anything like functions, includes and so on. I'm using this approach, to intercept (1.) outputs in my controller flow, and to intercept (2.) the view's output, so I can compose them later (for example to render PHP errors into a debug div.

Comment: thank you. i'm glad u understood the problem.:) i really really appreciate your help.:)